# How to check if the SEO company is making backlinks to our Magento store?

Tags: seo

The SEO company suppose to be making "backlinks" to our Magento store. Is there any way for me to check these?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO specifically and not Magento. It could be any other site/system you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my favorite tools is the Moz Open Site Explorer (https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/) for checking links, especially since there is a "just discovered" tab. However, they should be providing you with a list of backlinks so that you can check them yourself. If they aren't, perhaps you should ask for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. 
Just ask them how many backlinks they created for your website. 
Ask them to share the work report and how many backlinks they created for website.

Or
Use Google webmaster --> Link to Us Section